# Is a GUID without hyphens safe?

Tags: guid, uniqueidentifier

I've read various things about guids and how safe they are for not repeating the same value. I have a slight twist on the question though: Guids seem to always use hyphens to break them into chunks. If I dispose of these hyphens, does it hurt the uniqueness of the number in any way? If i recall, each block is always padded out to the same number of digits, so if that is true I would assume they should not suffer from removing the hyphens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct.  Hyphens are just for formatting.  If you look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html you'll notice all the different formats are really the same UID.

Comment: The same can be said for the braces at both ends (seen in Microsoft-related code).